# Crash dagger when build project

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

When i try to build a project for generating Dagger's files build fails with an exception.
Could you please tell me how to fix it or at least in what direction look.

> e:
>   /home/hodzi/Projects/StudioProjects/StackViewer/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/hodzi/stackviewer/di/AppComponent.java:6:
>   error: [com.hodzi.stackviewer.questions.di.QuestionsComponent]
>   com.hodzi.stackviewer.questions.di.QuestionsComponent has conflicting
>   scopes: e:
>
> e: public abstract interface AppComponent { e:                 ^ e:
>   com.hodzi.stackviewer.di.AppComponent also has @Singleton e:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while
>   annotation processing     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:138)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:154)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:58)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:889)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:916)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:888)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:385)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while
>   annotation processing     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)   at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:377)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:68)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:368)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:133)
>     ... 30 more

**Components:**

1) AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, NetModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(app: App)

    fun plus(questionsModule: QuestionsModule): QuestionsComponent
}
```

2) QuestionsComponent

```
@Singleton
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(QuestionsModule::class))
interface QuestionsComponent {
    fun inject(questionsActivity: QuestionsActivity)
}
```

**Modules:**

1) AppModule

```
@Module
class AppModule(val application: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): Context = application

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPrefs(context: Context): SharedPreferences =
            context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}
```

2) QuestionsModule

```
@Module
class QuestionsModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    fun provideQuestionsPresenter(questionsInteractor: QuestionsInteractor): QuestionsPresenter =
        QuestionsPresenter(questionsInteractor)

    @Provides @Singleton
    fun provideQuestionsInteractor(api : Api): QuestionsInteractor = QuestionsInteractor(api)
}
```

**App:**

```
class App : Application() {
    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .netModule(NetModule())
            .appModule(AppModule(this))
            .build()

    }

    val questionsComponent: QuestionsComponent by lazy {
        appComponent.plus(QuestionsModule())
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Injector.inject(this)
        NetUtils.init(this)
    }
}
```

If it helps then I attach a link to the [githab](https://github.com/ValeriyMakarshin/StackViewer/pull/2/files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined both `AppComponent` and `QuestionsComponent` as `@Singleton`, so which one is responsible for that scope? That is exactly what the error says. Remove the annotation from one of them.

Comment: When I removing one singleton I'll get "(unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings"

Comment: @Valeriy So you have to define your own custom scope. The tutorial you are following should cover this